# Writing a function which creates A Jagged 2D Array of Zeros in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I need to write a function which creates a 2D array with rows of different number of columns. Here's the code I've tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// program which allocates and returns a 2D int array full of zeros
int** make_zeros_jagged(int rows, int* array){
// dynamically allocate space for array
   int** result = malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);
  if(result==NULL){
    printf("allocation error\n");
    return NULL;
  }

// dynamically allocate space for each row
  for(int row=0; row<rows;row++){
    // put error handling here
    int cols = (sizeof(array[row])/sizeof(int));
      printf("\n col: %d\n", cols); // ----------> always returns 1  
    result[row]=malloc(sizeof(int)*cols);
      for(int col=0; col<cols; col++){
      result[row][col]= 0;
      printf("%d ", result[row][col]);
    }
      printf("\n");
  }
    return result;
}


// driver code for building array
int main(void){

// declare and build 2d array
    int rows = 3;
    int row1[5] ;
    int row2[4] ;
    int row3[3] ;

    int* array[] = { row1, row2, row3 };
    int** newarray;
    newarray = make_zeros_jagged(3,*array);

  return 0;
}
```

The expected result should be

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0
```

but my code returns

```
0 
0 
0
```

I'm wondering if I should include the number of columns of each row in the parameter of the function? But I'm not sure how to do it either. Reading the number of columns into an array? Or my method can work as well? Please help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: `sizeof(array[row])` == `sizeof(int)`, given `int * array`

Comment: You seem to mix up allocation as stack variables and allocation via `malloc`. You are currently trying to allocate both: Static variables using `int row1[5];` inside `main`and via malloc in your function. Which do you really want: `malloc`-allocated arrays, or just an array of pointers to your statically-sized arrays in `main`?

Comment: @rtoijala OP use `rowN`arrays as a 'template' for a malloc-ed one but failed with a size determining.

Comment: Note that you are not creating a "2D array", "jagged" or not.  You are creating an array of pointers to 1D arrays where the 1D arrays are of different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the number of columns for each row in an array. Your code is passing pointers to arrays of the wanted lengths, but you cannot get their lengths from the pointers.

The code below takes the number of rows, plus an array with the length of each column. It allocates the wanted jagged array, initializing it to zero with the `calloc` call.

```
int** make_zeros_jagged_resizable(int rows, int* cols) {
    // Allocate array for pointers.
    int** result = malloc(sizeof(*result) * rows);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("allocation error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate each of the rows and fill them with zeros.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        result[i] = calloc(cols[i], sizeof(*result[i]));

        if (result[i] == NULL) {
            printf("allocation error\n");
            // Free all the already-allocated rows.
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                free(result[j]);
            }
            free(result);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note that the code above requires many calls to `calloc`, which can be slow for large numbers of rows. Also, the rows may be far away from each other in memory. If you typically go through the whole 2D array, it can be better to allocate the whole block of ints in a single call, and then just set pointers to point into that single block. This has the disadvantage that you cannot resize individual rows anymore. See the code below.

```
int** make_zeros_jagged(int rows, int* cols) {
    // Allocate array for pointers.
    int** result = malloc(sizeof(*result) * rows);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("allocation error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Compute total number of ints.
    size_t total_ints = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        total_ints += cols[i];
    }

    // Allocate array for ints, and zero it.
    // This assumes that you do not want to resize the rows
    // individually afterwards.
    int* space = calloc(total_ints, sizeof(*space));
    if (space == NULL) {
        printf("allocation error\n");
        free(result);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Fill the pointer array with pointers to the correct
    // parts of the int array.
    size_t pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        result[i] = &space[pos];
        pos += cols[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```